# How to keep letters fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I am working on a project that keeps text private on the web. A way to post text and prevent it from being printed or copy and pasted easily.

I do this by breaking up the alphabet into three separate fonts. A top font a bottom font and a middle font. To make the source readable I loop over the fonts and like animation the text should be readable.

My problem is that the browser shifts the letters around slightly left and slightly up and down.  Is there a way to stop this?
Here is a link to an example.

https://afternoon-sierra-56089.herokuapp.com/

Thank you.

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. You mean that the browser causes what you labelled as "loop", and you want to stop that happening?

Comment: No I want it stop shifting the letters and keep them fixed. So that as the browser loops over the three different fonts. The partial fonts appear to be whole and become readable.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you can simply do the following to prevent copying in the browser from a CSS stand point.

```
body{-webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;}
```

to fix your issue though, it appears Blayer is undefined, so the style isn't being properly applied